# WinApi tabcontrol

Tags: winapi, windows, c++, visual-studio, usercontrol

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на WinApi сделать вкладки с крестиком. Т.е. что бы были не просто вкладки, а в углу каждой вкладки был бы крестик при нажатии на который вкладка бы закрывалась. Т.е. как в браузерах. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Крестик дорисовывается на `WM_NCPAINT`.

Comment: Если вам нужен сложный UI, почему вы пишете на голом WinAPI?